# When Xcode spontaneously adjusts a storyboard, has anyone had it actually break anything?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When I open an existing project in Xcode it immediately adjusts certain values in a storyboard. Here's a part of a storyboard's diff:

```
-    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="49.5" width="320" height="140"/>
+    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="50" width="320" height="140"/>
     <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
     <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="pcz-Xs-p1T" id="8G9-Je-Ou9">
-        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="139.5"/>
+        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="140"/>
```

The changes happens only once, so it looks like Xcode updates the project to the recent format.

So, should I commit these changes to the project repository or just ignore them?

It is worth noting there're other programmers working on a project, and they might not be using latest Xcode versions.

**Update.** I can hardly see how this question is "opinion-based". The changes made by Xcode are either breaking or not. If there's even a small chance that these changes will break the code, they should not be staged for commit.

Another concern is that theese changes would be reverted by another versions of Xcode, which results in polluting multiple commits with useless edits.

I would also love to know why Xcode is not happy with half-points anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be safe - I've never had it actually break my project.  And there isn't really a good alternative. Complexity is exponential with size.  So, many smaller changes are easier to review than a few large ones.  But...

I do find it incredibly annoying that merely viewing a storyboard introduces a change to it. And it's especially irksome when one Xcode-induced change triggers others.

But the thing I like least is that Xcode hijacks my agenda.  I'm trying to manage commits for changes in some tricky code interactions, but end up having to switch contexts and deal with something utterly unrelated: review miscellaneous tweaks to a storyboard.

All that said, as a practical matter, the best choice for me seems to be to "pay as you go", and commit unrequested Storyboard changes as they occur.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're pretty safe.

All that's changing there is the position of a couple of views within the storyboard, and it's only changing by half a pixel. That shouldn't mess anything up.

For the hassle ignoring them could bring, I'd definitely commit them.

Comment: It's half a point, not half a pixel.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a storyboard xcode sometimes changes the toolversion and if you are using size classes it changes the frame of the view.
If you have just opened the storyboard and get these changes than don't push them because the other developer if he is working on that storyboard will get conflicts.
If you yourself have made some changes than push them and if their are conflicts than you can fix them by opening the storyboard as source code and removing the conflicts
Note:The better approach is to divide views in different storyboards so that one developer works on one storyboard at a time and you won't get any conflicts just make sure that your team does not push unnecessary files of storyboard that they haven't worked on